# javascript call from appDelegate : phonegap iOS

Tags: ios, xcode4, cordova

How I got the instance of phonegap webview in the appDelegate.m class

I want to call javascript function on the notification receive(i.e. from the appDelegate class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved for me...

just calling with `self.webView` in `didReceiveRemoteNotification`

like

```
NSString * jsCallBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"pushCallBack();"];
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallBack];
```

Comment: in cordova > 3.0, use: self.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString

Comment: @Amit Battan: The callback fails when the notification is tapped while the app is in background state. Any clue why?